# SVG images are not being retrieved when the project is deployed on the server

Tags: flutter

In my Flutter project, I have included various image formats such as JPG, PNG, and SVG in the asset folder.

However, I am encountering an issue specifically with SVG files not being retrieved after the project is deployed on the Firebase server.

But in localhost svg format will retrieve fine. I am seeking assistance from anyone who can provide guidance or support in resolving this particular scenario.

Comment: SVG files are sometimes much heavier then png/jpeg. If that's the case for your files, you might want to check if you are getting 504/408/any other timeout-related issues.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're having trouble with SVG files not showing up right after uploading your Flutter project to a Firebase server. They were showing up fine on localhost. It's possible that this is happening because of how Firebase Hosting serves files or how your Flutter app handles them.

When you set up [Firebase Hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config) in **firebase.json**, make sure that SVG files are served with the right MIME type. You can do this by telling SVG files what labels to use:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "headers": [
      {
        "source": "**/*.svg",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Content-Type",
            "value": "image/svg+xml"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Also, ensure that the paths to your SVG files in your Flutter app match exactly with those on the server. Pay attention to case sensitivity and path correctness, as discrepancies can lead to files not being found on the server.

I'm not sure if you are using the flutter_svg package but if you are not try using it as it will help a lot.

**Tip: Add some more error screenshots and the approach you are using.**